# changes not reflected in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to setup a new "a" component using JS function which is called , using following :

```
function add_div(data){
    mydiv = document.getElementById("new_twt");
    var link =document.createElement("a");
    var text = "you have new conversations";
    link.setAttribute("name",text);
    link.onclick=function(){new_tweet(data);};
    mydiv.appendChild(link);
  }
```

Changes are not reflecting on the webpage , however if I use some other element such as button or new div it gets created instantly, am I missing something?

Comment: Note that unless you're declaring it somewhere, you're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* with `mydiv`.

Comment: Other than the (possible) implicit global and the odd `name` attribute (did you mean `title`?), provided you have an element with the `id` `"new_twt"` when you call `add_div`, that looks like it should work.

Comment: Why the `jquery` tag when you're doing everything with raw JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function add_div(data){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("new_twt");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = "you have new conversations";
    link.name = text;
    link.href = '#';
    link.innerHTML = 'link';
    link.onclick=function(){ new_tweet(data); return false; };
    mydiv.appendChild(link);
}
```

- I've added link text (innerHTML) so you can actually see the link
- I've also added "href" so the link behaves as a link (with this you need to prevent default link action, like "return false" in the event listener, to prevent browser from jumping to the top)

Comment: is it necessary to provide link.href and link.innerHTML

Comment: "href" is not required, but without "innerHTML" the link will be empty, so unless you've styled it to be visible (display: block, image bg) you will not see the link.

Comment: thanks for the help, just in situation i call this function again or thrice the link gets appended 3 times how can I avoid this , i mean is it possible to replace child i.e previous link with same function

Comment: give the link a unique ID and before adding it - check if the id exists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("new_twt");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm"); //or #
aTag.innerHTML = "you have new conversations";
aTag.onclick=function(){new_tweet(data);};
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Here is working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCUTE/7/).